# Can't figure out correct format to conver object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to convert a date in a .txt file that looks like '08-abr-19'.

The file is in Spanish so that's why April looks like 'abr' instead of 'apr'

I have tried using several formats as suggested in this site: http://strftime.org/

However, none of them seem to work. The most obvious to me was:

```
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'],format='%d-%b-%y')
```

I get an error of this type: ValueError: time data '08-abr-19' does not match format '%d-%b-%y' (match)

As a note, I create a dataframe by importing the .txt file. Column 'a' contains the dates in the format I explained in the first line.

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work if you change it to apr instead of abr?

Comment: It does. Will check the suggested duplicate. Thanks